# Firefox not receiving django csrf_token

Tags: python, django, firefox, django-csrf

I am submitting a ajax form in django and using

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
```

to get csrf_token. The form is working well in chrome. But in firefox the value of csrf_token is null and its giving 403 forbidden error. I am not receiving csrf_token in console when I checked cookies in console. Why django is not giving csrf_token to firefox browser ?

Comment: Did you check `getCookie('csrftoken')` returns any value in Firefox?

Comment: Please show the code that is rendering the form.

Comment: form is a ajax form and I am posting serialized data to django with csrftoken that I get from cookie using this `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'))`

Comment: If you look at the network traffic in the browser inspector, do you see the csrf token there?

Comment: Its behaving weird, when I log in the application , I get csrf_token and then it stays there even after login. But if I clear all the cookies of the browser, then    I don't get any csrf_token till I log in . Why I am not getting csrf_token without login ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following decorator to the view that generates the page that holds the form

@ensure_csrf_cookie

From the Django Docs -

> Page uses AJAX without any HTML form
>
> A page makes a POST request via AJAX, and the page does not have an
>   HTML form with a csrf_token that would cause the required CSRF cookie
>   to be sent.
>
> Solution: use ensure_csrf_cookie() on the view that sends the page.